# IntelliJ align multiple lines of code vertically

Tags: intellij-idea, vertical-alignment, pycharm

I am wondering how to align (the keyboard shortcut) a line or a block of code with the previous line, so that they have the same indention or starting from the same column in `IntelliJ` and `PyCharm`.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "Emacs Tab" could help you. You can use setting search to find it or you can go `Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> Keymap`. It is editor action and in some Keymap settings it doesn't have assigned key shortcut. I personally prefer remap Tab key to this action.